# Linking against two similar libraries with cmake

Tags: linux, linker, cmake, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I have a problem with cmake and linking my application:
I' working on an existing project. This project uses a modified libjpeg (a static lib) and my executable is linked against it.

```
target_link_libraries( myprog jpeglib )
```

Now I want to add a new feature that uses the turbojpeg lib.

```
add_library( newfeature SHARED ${LIBVNCSERVER_SOURCES})
set_target_properties( newfeature PROPERTIES DEFINE_SYMBOL DLLDEFINE)
target_link_libraries( newfeature turbojpeg-static)
target_link_libraries( newfeature LINK_INTERFACE_LIBRARIES)
```

My program will be linked against this shared library:

```
target_link_libraries ( myprog jpeglib newfeature )
```

Under Windows everything works fine. But if I use this feature under Linux, I get an error:

```
JPEG Error: JPEG parameter struct mismatch: library thinks size is 488, caller expects 504
```

This error is generated from libjpeg.

Everything I found on Google doesn't work.
I guess that the shared library newfeature uses the jpeglib from myprog although newfeature is statically linked against the turbojpeg lib. newfeature should be a standalone .so or .dll file
If I changed the linking order I got the same error, but it is generated from turbojpeg.

Linking myprog against turbojpeg-static is not possible because it is not compatible with the modified libjpeg.

Can anyone help? Is my assumption right?

Comment: Is that error coming when you are calling a `jpeglib` function, or a `newfeature` one?  It looks like your `turbojpeg` library may simply need to be rebuilt against the same base version of `libjpeg` you've been using previously.

Comment: The error comes when I call a newfeature function. I will try the rebuilding, thanks for the hint

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution:

I added `--exclude-libs,ALL` to the linker command of `newfeature` with this cmake command:

```
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Wl,--exclude-libs,ALL")
```

The problem was that the symbols from my `turbojpeg-static` were exported by my `newfeature.so` and therefore visible from "outside". The linker firstly finds the symbols from the `libjpeg`. While linking `myprog` against `newfeature.so`, the linker finds the references from my `newfeature` methods to `turbojpeg-static` and overwrites them.

I hope I can help others with same problem. Please let me know if something is unclear or incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are statically linking `libjpeg` into your executable, but now you're trying to add an indirect dependency on (`libjpeg-turbo`), which is another implementation of the same API.

This is a problem because there are now two possible resolutions for every public API symbol (function name, etc.) in the `libjpeg` API.  Most libraries don't support two versions of themselves in one executable, and certainly two different libraries implementing the same interface are unlikely to do so.

If anything you got lucky in that `libjpeg` is checking a version from its header files (at build time) against its library (at runtime).  This sort of problem often goes undetected when libraries don't build in these sorts of checks.

You should try to make `newfeature` depend not on `libjpeg-turbo` and instead satisfy it with your own `libjpeg` which seems to be a fixed requirement from your description.

Comment: I'm wondering because the `newfeature` shared lib is linked against `turbojpeg` and should be independent from the `libjpeg` that is statically linked by `myprog`

Comment: Can you clarify which of these you are using? http://www.libjpeg-turbo.org/About/TurboJPEG - "turbojpeg" or "libjpeg-turbo"?  Such confusing naming!  You say you're using "turbojpeg" but is it implemented by "libjpeg-turbo" or are you using another implementation?

Comment: Sorry for that, I'm using libjpeg-turbo C library (and renamed it)

Comment: OK I see; I've updated my answer to reflect this.  It's the same symptoms, basically the same diagnosis, but slightly different advice on how to proceed.